# WP7 Region format testing

Tags: windows-phone-7, wp7test

Is there an easy way to test that your application runs properly across all region formats? Or would I need to cumbersomely set the region format, reboot the phone and then deploy my application?

The reason I ask is because I have recently discovered my app does not run properly when Region Format is set to Russian because decimal places are represented as "," instead of ".". Thus in Russian the following code throws an exception:

```
string version = "2.5"
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(version);
```

whereas the following is correct:

```
string version = "2,5"
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(version);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the Culture:

```
string version = "2.5"
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(version, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

[List of all Cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: wow thanks! I guess that gets around the particular issue that I had!